# How to troubleshoot code in the case of big data

Tags: python, debugging, pandas, bigdata

I'm trying to implement [this python solution to count the number of lines with identical content in the first few columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24581967/count-lines-with-same-value-in-column-in-python) of a table. Here is my code:

```
#count occurrences of reads
import pandas as pd
#pd.options.display.large_repr = 'info'
#pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 100000000)
#pd.set_option('display.width',50000)

import sys
file1 = sys.argv[1]
file2 = file1[:4] + '_multi_nobidir_count.soap'

df = pd.read_csv(file1,sep='\t',header=None)
df.columns = ['v0','v1','v2','v3','v4','v5','v6','v7','v8','v9','v10','v11']
df['v3']=df.groupby(['v0','v1','v2']).transform(sum).v3
df.to_csv(file2,sep='\t',index=False,header=False)
```

It worked fine with the test data (200 lines) but gives me the following error when I apply it to the real data (20 million lines):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "count_same_reads.py", line 14, in <module>
    df['v3']=df.groupby(['v0','v1','v2']).transform(sum).v3
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2732, in transform
    return self._transform_item_by_item(obj, fast_path)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py", line 2799, in _transform_item_by_item
    raise TypeError('Transform function invalid for data types')
TypeError: Transform function invalid for data types
```

How do I go about troubleshooting, to find out why I am getting this error?

[EDIT] Uncommenting the `pd.options.` and `pd.set_option` lines did not change the outcome.

[EDIT2] Taking into consideration some of the replies below, I ran the following code on my data to output any lines of data that do not have a number in the 4th column:

```
#test data type
import sys
file1 = sys.argv[1]

def is_number(s):
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

with open(file1, 'r') as data:
    for row in data:
        a = row.strip().split()[3]
        if is_number(a) == False:
            print row.strip()
```

This worked on the test data in which I changed one of the rows' fourth column value from `1` to `e`, it output only the line containing the letter instead of a number. I ran it on the original big data but no lines were returned.

Comment: Maybe transforming only the `v3` column works: `df.v3 = df.groupby(['v0','v1','v2']).v3.transform(sum)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception you have received is `TypeError` which hints at problems with the file. But with large files it is always possible that there are, e.g., memory problems with the code handling the comparisons. So, you have two possibilities:

- the file is broken
- the code (yours or `pandas`'s) is broken

In order to debug this, you may try to feed your file into your code in pieces. At some point you have isolated the problem. It may be one of the two:

- no matter which *n* lines you take, it throws an exception (but not with *n*-1 lines); memory management or something else is broken
- the problems can be isolated onto a single line or lines of your data file; the data file is broken

I second `merlin2011`'s guess: there is something unexpected in your file. It is unlikely that `pandas` will choke with only 200 000 000 records.

Comment: Thank you. I tried checking the original data to see whether the column I am counting contains anything else than numbers, but apparently it doesn't... I edited the OP to show how I did that. But do you think this is enough to rule out the "file is broken" option?

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not. It is possible that you have bad data in one of the other columns you use (columns 1, 2, 3). On the other hand, if you are not short of HDD space, telling linux to `tail +1234567 mydata.csv | head -n 10000` to produce the test files does not take that much time.

Comment: I resolved this but forgot to check the answer. My data file was indeed broken :)

Answer (score 2):

Open the file `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pandas-0.14.0-py2.7-linux-x86_64.egg/pandas/core/groupby.py`, go to line 2799.

Right before  the following statement, in the same indent level, add a line to print the value of the offending data.

```
raise TypeError('Transform function invalid for data types')
```

Now, right before the `TypeError` is thrown, you will know what data caused the error.

Given that you are trying to sum, I would speculate that you have a non-numeric value in your column, but I do not have your data, so that is pure speculation.

---

I have taken a quick look at the code region around where the error occurs, and it appears that you should be this case be inspecting the object `obj` before the `TypeError` is raised.

```
for i, col in enumerate(obj):
    try:
        output[col] = self[col].transform(wrapper)
        inds.append(i)
    except Exception:
        pass

if len(output) == 0:  # pragma: no cover
    raise TypeError('Transform function invalid for data types')
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean I should add `print obj`?

Answer (score 2):

Here's how to troublshoot something like this:

Create a function to wrap the operation (this will be a fair bit slower as its not cythonized), but should catch your error.

```
def f(x):
    try:
        return x.sum()
    except:
        import pdb; pdb.set_trace()


df['v3']=df.groupby(['v0','v1','v2']).transform(f).v3
```